# Casting in D - type coercion: preserving bit pattern, without value conversions

Tags: casting, type-conversion, d, type-coercion

I'd like to convert the type of a value to an unsigned integer of the exact same width preserving the exact bit pattern. So for example a 64-bit float would become typed as a ulong, but the bit pattern would be identical. The input type is unspecified but I don't need to deal with input values bigger than will fit in one of the usual D integral types, so no aggregates or in-memory objects.

1. I've had a go at first generating a type that is some kind of unsigned integer, could do with suggestions on how to do this properly, as I ought to make some decision about dealing with the constness and immutability of the input type.
2. Then having obtained a suitable type, I force the compiler to avoid value conversions by doing something like

   `( * cast(const T_uint_result *) & input_val )`

which seems to work, having examined the generated code, but I am very dissatisfied with this. A lot of the time a straight cast would be fine, but that isn't safe in general for my purposes because of the possibility of the compiler changing the bit pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there is no built-in way to do it other than the workaround you posted. What you could do is writing a function for you doing that like this:

```d
pragma(inline, true)
T bitCast(T, Orig)(scope Orig val) pure nothrow @nogc @system {
    return *(cast(T*) &val);
}
```

Use like this:

```d
float f = 4.5f;
uint i = f.bitCast!uint;
writeln(i); // 1083179008
```

A safer alternative would be using an union, though you need to make sure you actually use the correct type there, otherwise the value might be something else as compared to the function above because of different widths (float/double conversion):

```d
union DoubleLong {
    double value;
    long integer;
}
```

Otherwise if your goal is actually to get or set the fraction, exponent and sign of a float or double, you might as well use [std.bitmanip.FloatRep](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_bitmanip.html#.FloatRep) or [std.bitmanip.DoubleRep](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_bitmanip.html#.DoubleRep)

There you can also manipulate these parts, usage would be like this:

```d
FloatRep fr;
fr.value = 4.5f; // your float here
fr.exponent = fr.exponent - 1; // reduces exponent, it's a property, so no unary operators
writeln(fr.value); // 2.25, it's divided by 2 because it's binary
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a `union`. e.g.

```
union U
{
    float f;
    uint i;
}
U u;
u.f = input;
output = u.i;
```

And if you want a function out of it, you could do something like

```
import std.algorithm;

auto reinterpretAsInteger(T)(T t)
    if([1, 2, 4, 8].canFind(T.sizeof))
{
    union U
    {
        T input;
        static if(T.sizeof == 1)
            ubyte output;
        else static if(T.sizeof == 2)
            ushort output;
        else static if(T.sizeof == 4)
            uint output;
        else static if(T.sizeof == 8)
            ulong output;
    }

    U u;
    u.input = t;
    return u.output;
}
```